# zoom:140% magnify all element but svg <image> element in safari

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, raphael, magnify

I use raphael.js for drawing ,I add image in page by:

`paper = Raphael("manipulate-canvas",0,0, 640, 480)`

`paper.image("assets/irm.jpg", 0, 0, 640, 480)`

when I injected stylesheet in safari ,the stylesheet contain css `body {zoom: 140%}`, all elements in the page are magnified but svg's `<image>`,so the image does't fill in the whole svg(`<svg>` is magnified). how can I magnify svg's `<image>` and make it fill in the whole svg in this case.I tried to add attributes to `<svg>` and `<image>` like this:

`$("svg").attr({height:480,width:640,viewBox:"0 0 640 480",preserveAspectRatio:"xMidYMid meet"})`

`$("svg image").attr({"preserveAspectRatio":"xMidYMid meet",height:480,width:640})`

but It didn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix it. thanks a lot!!!